# What is the latest version of Sun One Web Server?

Tags: webserver, sunone

I could not find the version number anywhere in the sun's website. Anyone help me to find the latest version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun ONE is no longer distributed.  The latest version of its successor, Sun Java System Web Server, is 7.0.   See the [FAQ](http://www.sun.com/software/products/web_srvr/faq_stub.xml) on Sun's website.